# How can i prove this inequality without using AM-GM?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

How can i prove that if $a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}=1$ then $a_{1}+a_{2}+ \cdots+a_{n}\geq n$ without using AM-GM?

I tried this:

If $a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}\cdots a_{n}=1$ then assume without loss of generality that $$\max{\{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},\ldots,a_{n}}\}=a_{1}\geq 1$$ and $$\min{\{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},\ldots,a_{n}}\}=a_{2}\leq 1$$ then $$(a_{1}-1)(1-a_{2})\geq 0 \Longrightarrow a_{1}+a_{2}-a_{1}a_{2}\geq 1 \qquad(1)$$
since $a_{1}a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},\cdots,a_{n}$ are $n-1$ positive numbers with product equal to 1, by inductive hypothesis we have: $$a_{1}a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}+\cdots +a_{n}\geq n-1\qquad(2)$$ adding the inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get: $$a_{1}+a_{2}-a_{1}a_{2}+a_{1}a_{2}+a_{3}+\cdots +a_{n}\geq 1+(n-1) \Longrightarrow a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n} \geq n$$

but i dont know if the proof is done.

Comment: This **is** AM-GM.

Comment: It's done.It's one way to prove AGM inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $b_i$ be positive, and let $M=\prod b_i$. Let $a_i=\frac{b_i}{M^{1/n}}$. Then $\prod a_i=1$. If we know that $\sum a_i\ge n$, then we know that $\frac{\sum b_i}{n}\ge M^{1/n}$, which is the general Arithmetic Mean Geometric Mean Inequality.

Thus AM-GM is an immediate consequence of the inequality in the post. If we prove that inequality, we have proved AM-GM.

Comment: Indeed that is why I'm trying to prove this inequality.

Comment: The argument is correct.